# Как считать нажатие клавиши за пределами моей программы?

Tags: c#, события

Как через event отследить нажатие клавиши на клавиатуре на рабочем столе или в другой программе?

Comment: Придется написать службу, которая будет запускаться с ОС и вися в памяти отслеживать клавиатурные события. Но здесь запрещено давать советы по написанию клав.логеров, вирусов и проч. дряни.

Comment: спасибо мне просто пряталку програм захотелось сделать